Problem with selecting a specific option available for an unsearchable drop-down menu with selenium in python
As the attached image shows (the highlighted one), in a web scraping process with Selenium Python, I am attempting to select a specific option available for an unsearchable drop-down menu.

Inspired by this link and this link, I have written code to do this task. But the code does not work giving this error:
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62647/devtools/browser/02814b76-d962-4afa-83dc-8cfd7c7a44ac
Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that has dynamic-sized tensors (tensor#58 is a dynamic-sized tensor)

The code is (first attempt):
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
# creating bank account
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
bank_branch="پارسيان"

bankbrunch_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'bankAccount.bankBranch.bank.bankId')
for option in bankbrunch_element.find_elements(By.NAME, 'option'):
    if option.text == bank_branch:
        option.click() 
        break

I have also tried this code (second attempt)
bankbrunch_element =WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
 EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='bankAccount.bankBranch.bank.bankId']"))) 
for option in bankbrunch_element.find_elements(By.NAME, 'option'):
    if option.text == bank_branch:
        option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver
        break

But it also fails to do the task, giving this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B659B125+29573]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B650FF50]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B63CB6EA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B641F815]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B641FA6C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B646B917]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B644733F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B64686BC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B64470A3]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B64112DF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B6412441]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B68CC76D+3377613]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B6917B67+3685831]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B690CF8B+3641835]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B665B2A6+816390]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B651B25F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B6517084]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B6517220]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B650607F]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF9938B7374+20]
       RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF9951DCC91+33]

I have also tried this code (third attempt):
bankbrunch_element = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
 EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='bankAccount.bankBranch.bank.bankId']"))))

bankbrunch_element.select_by_visible_text(bank_branch) 

but it also fails to do the task, giving this error:
"C:\Users\s.kalantari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 105, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B659B125+29573]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B650FF50]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B63CB6EA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B641F815]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B641FA6C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B646B917]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B644733F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B64686BC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B64470A3]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B64112DF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B6412441]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B68CC76D+3377613]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B6917B67+3685831]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B690CF8B+3641835]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B665B2A6+816390]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B651B25F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B6517084]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B6517220]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B650607F]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF9938B7374+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF9951DCC91+33

The HTML code of the drop-down list is :
<select name="bankAccount.bankBranch.bank.bankId" style="width:130px;">

the full html code is:
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html dir="rtl">

<head>
  <title>
      
      
          سبدگردانی
      
  </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="/styles/global.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel = "icon" href = "https://www.rayanhamafza.com/Assets/11/favicon.ico?version=20210928105149" type = "image/x-icon">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/global.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getIndexOf(_keys_, str) {
            try {
                for (i = 0; i < _keys_.length; i++) {
                    if (_keys_[i] === str) {
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {}
            return -1;
        }

        function disableForm(theform) {
            if (document.all || document.getElementById) {
                for (i = 0; i < theform.length; i++) {
                    var tempobj = theform.elements[i];
                    if (tempobj.type.toLowerCase() === "submit" || tempobj.type.toLowerCase() === "reset") {
                        tempobj.disabled = true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        function enableForm(theform) {
                        if (document.all || document.getElementById) {
                for (i = 0; i < theform.length; i++) {
                    var tempobj = theform.elements[i];
                    if (tempobj.type.toLowerCase() === "submit" || tempobj.type.toLowerCase() === "reset") {
                        tempobj.disabled = false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        function returnfalse() {
          return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>



















 
 
 



<script type='text/javascript' src='dwr/interface/Manager.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='dwr/engine.js'></script>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100vw">
<tr width="100%" height="10">
  <td width="5%" rowspan="3" vAlign=center align=middle>
    <a href="index.do">
      <img src="images/company.gif" border=0 height="60">
    </a>
  </td>
  <td width="50%" vAlign=center align="right" rowspan="3">
    <img src="images/system_name.gif" border=0>
  </td>
  <td width="45%" align="left" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="left" >
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="45%" Valign="bottom" align="left" style="height: 20px;
  
  background-position: left top; background-repeat: no-repeat; text-align: left;">
    
    کاربر
    :&nbsp;راهبر راهبر
    (اصلي)
    &nbsp;
    <a href="changePass.do?method=list">
      کلمه عبور
    </a>&nbsp;
    <a href="logout.do?id=1727608501404">
      خروج
    </a>&nbsp;
    
  </td>
</tr>
<tr width="100%" class="navItem">
<td class="navItem" colspan="3" width="100%">
<table width="100%" border=0>
<tr width="100%">
<td width="90%">
  
  

















 
 
 



<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="fa">
<title>Menu</title>
<style type="text/css">

    #dropmenudiv {
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px #6495ed; /* taghire rang be kamrang */
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        font: normal 12px Tahoma;
        line-height: 18px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    #dropmenudiv a {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        text-indent: 3px; /*border-bottom: 1px solid white;*/
        border-bottom: 1px;
        padding: 3px 0;
        text-decoration: none; /*font-weight: bold;*/
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    #dropmenudiv a:hover {
    /*hover background color*/
        background-color: #6495ed; /* taghire rang be kamrang */
    }

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

function popup(url) {
 params  = 'width='+screen.width;
 params += ', height='+screen.height;
 params += ', top=0, left=0'
 params += ', fullscreen=yes';

 newwin=window.open(url,'windowname4', params);
 if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
 return false;
}


/***********************************************
 * AnyLink Drop Down Menu- © Dynamic Drive (www.dynamicdrive.com)
 * This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
 * Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
 ***********************************************/

//Contents for menu 1
var menu1 = new Array()
index = 0;


menu1[index++] = '<hr>'


//menu1[index++] = '<a href="branch.do?new_search=true">شعب و باجه‌ها</a>'
menu1[index++] = '<a href="branch.do?new_search=true">شعب</a>'


menu1[index++] = '<a href="appUser.do?new_search=true">کاربران</a>'

menu1[index++] = '<a href="appRole.do?new_search=true">گروه‌های کاربری</a>'

menu1[index++] = '<a href="logonGroup.do?method=list">گروه‌های بهره بردار</a>'



menu1[index++] = '<hr>'

menu1[index++] = '<a href="appParam.do?method=listParam&new_search=true">تنظیم پارامترها</a>'

menu1[index++] = '<a href="appParam.do?method=listAccounting&new_search=true">تنظیم حساب‌ها</a>'


menu1[index++] = '<a href="wageExcept.do">تنظیم عدم احتساب کارمزد</a>'


menu1[index++] = '<a href="rpReason.do?new_search=true">علت‌های دریافت/پرداخت</a>'



menu1[index++] = '<a href="voucherType.do?new_search=true">انواع اسناد حسابداری</a>'



menu1[index++] = '<a href="closingLevel.do">مراحل بستن حساب</a>'



menu1[index++] = '<hr>'

menu1[index++] = '<a href="printFormat.do?new_search=true">فرمت چاپ</a>'

menu1[index++] = '<a href="businessCalendar.do?new_search=true">تقویم کاری</a>'


menu1[index++] = '<hr>'

menu1[index++] = '<a href="sendEmail.do?new_search=true">ارسال ایمیل</a>'

menu1[index++] = '<a href="sms.do?new_search=true">ارسال پیام کوتاه</a>'

menu1[index++] = '<a href="message.do?new_search=true">پیغام به کاربران</a>'



menu1[index++] = '<hr>'
var menu2 = new Array()
index = 0;



menu2[index++] = '<hr>'

menu2[index++] = '<a href="customerRiskGrade.do">طبقه ریسک مشتریان</a>'



menu2[index++] = '<a href="customerGroup.do">گروه‌های مشتریان</a>'



menu2[index++] = '<a href="customer.do?new_search=true&mode_=null">مشتریان</a>'
        
        
//menu2[index++]='<a href="portfolioAdjustment.do?new_search=true">استقرار سهام مشتریان</a>'



menu2[index++] = '<a href="customer.do?method=edit">مشتری جدید</a>'


menu2[index++] = '<hr>'

menu2[index++] = '<a href="industry.do?new_search=true">صنایع</a>'


menu2[index++] = '<a href="instrument.do?new_search=true">اوراق بهادار</a>'
        
//menu2[index++]='<a href="instrument.do?method=listPrice&new_search=true&search.instrumentPrice.fromDate=1403/06/29&search.instrumentPrice.toDate=1403/07/08">قیمت‌های روز</a>'
menu2[index++] = '<a href="instrument.do?method=listPrice&new_search=true">آمار قیمت اوراق بهادار</a>'


menu2[index++] = '<hr>'




menu2[index++] = '<a href="bank.do?new_search=true">بانک‌ها</a>'

menu2[index++] = '<a href="bank.do?method=listBankAccountType&new_search=true">نوع حساب</a>'

menu2[index++] = '<a href="bankBranch.do?new_search=true">شعب بانک‌ها</a>'

menu2[index++] = '<a href="bankAccount.do?new_search=true">حساب‌های بانکی</a>'

menu2[index++] = '<a href="cash.do?new_search=true">صندوق‌ها</a>'


menu2[index++] = '<a href="detailLedgerClass.do?new_search=true">طبقه تفصیلی ها</a>'



menu2[index++] = '<hr>'


menu2[index++] = '<a href="brokerage.do?new_search=true">کارگزاری‌های همکار</a>'


menu2[index++] = '<a href="fundUnit.do?new_search=true">صندوق های همکار</a>'

menu2[index++] = '<hr>'

var menu21 = new Array()
index = 0;

var menu3 = new Array()
index = 0;








menu3[index++] = '<hr>'



menu3[index++] = '<a href="spfile.do?search.spFile.fromDate=1403/06/29&search.spFile.toDate=1403/07/08&new_search=true">فایل‌های معاملات</a>'

menu3[index++] = '<a href="transaction.do?search.transaction.fromDate=1403/07/08&search.transaction.toDate=1403/07/08">پردازش معاملات</a>'

menu3[index++] = '<hr>'

menu3[index++] = '<a href="spfile.do?method=manualDBSEdit">ثبت دستی معاملات سبد اختصاصی</a>'

menu3[index++] = '<a href="spfile.do?method=dbsList&new_search=true">معاملات سبد اختصاصی</a>'

menu3[index++] = '<hr>'

var menu4 = new Array()
index = 0;





menu4[index++] = '<hr>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="nReceipt.do?new_search=true">دریافت‌ها</a>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="nReceipt.do?new_search=true&method=nreceiptList">رسید های دریافت</a>'


menu4[index++] = '<a href="nReceipt.do?method=edit">دریافت جدید</a>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="nreceivableCheck.do?new_search=true">پیگیری چک های دریافتنی</a>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="nwire.do?new_search=true">پیگیری حواله</a>'



menu4[index++] = '<hr>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="payment.do?new_search=true">پرداخت‌ها</a>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="paymentCheck.do?method=edit&type=check">پرداخت جدید</a>'
menu4[index++] = '<a href="paymentCheckGroup.do?method=editGroupCheck">پرداخت چک گروهی</a>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="payableCheck.do?new_search=true">پیگیری چک های پرداختنی</a>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="paymentCheck.do?method=printCheque">چاپ چک</a>'



menu4[index++] = '<hr>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="paymentOrderWithdraw.do?method=list&type=withdraw&new_search=true">دستور پرداخت های الکترونیک</a>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="paymentOrderWithdraw.do?method=edit&type=withdraw">دستور پرداخت الکترونیک جدید</a>'





menu4[index++] = '<hr>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="prtfBrokerCustomerBalance.do?new_search=true">انتقال مانده حساب سبد  نزد کارگزاریها</a>'



menu4[index++] = '<hr>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="prtfLoanInterestAdjustment.do?new_search=true">تسویه بهره وام سبدهای اختصاصی</a>'



menu4[index++] = '<hr>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="prtfBankProfitAdjustment.do?new_search=true">ما به التفاوت سود سپرده بانکی مشتریان</a>'

menu4[index++] = '<hr>'

menu4[index++] = '<a href="prtfWageVatAdjustment.do?new_search=true">مابه التفاوت کارمزد ها و مالیات بر ارزش افزوده</a>'



menu4[index++] = '<hr>'


var menu5 = new Array()
index = 0;



   menu5[index++] = '<hr>'


    menu5[index++] = '<a href="customerTransactionReport.do?method=list&new_search=true&fromMenu=true">ریز معاملات سبد اختصاصی</a>'


    menu5[index++] = '<a href="transaction.do?method=listSummary&new_search=true">خلاصه معاملات</a>'



    menu5[index++] = '<hr>'





    menu5[index++] = '<a href="customerReport.do?method=listStatementNew&new_search=true&fromMenu=true">گردش وجوه نقد سبد اختصاصی</a>'



    menu5[index++] = '<a href="prtfPortfolioReport.do?method=cashStatusReport">وضعیت نقدینگی سبدهای اختصاصی</a>'



    menu5[index++] = '<a href="prtfPortfolioReport.do?method=momentaryCashStatusReport">وضعیت نقدینگی لحظه ای سبدهای اختصاصی</a>'




    menu5[index++] = '<a href="prtfPortfolioReport.do?method=brokerFinancialStatus">وضعیت مالی سبدها نزد کارگزاران</a>'









    menu5[index++] = '<hr>'



    menu5[index++] = '<a href="prtfContract.do?method=contractStatus">وضعیت قراردادها</a>'





    menu5[index++] = '<a href="customerReport.do?method=listAsset&new_search=true">وضعیت دارایی سبد اختصاصی</a>'



    menu5[index++] = '<a href="customerReport.do?method=detailAsset&new_search=true">صورت دارایی سبد اختصاصی</a>'



    menu5[index++] = '<a href="prtfPortfolioReport.do?method=assetStructure&new_search=true">ترکیب دارایی های سبد اختصاصی</a>'



    menu5[index++] = '<a href="prtfPortfolioReport.do">عملکرد سبد اختصاصی</a>'



    menu5[index++] = '<a href="prtfContractAccountingReport.do">صورتهای مالی سبد اختصاصی</a>'




    menu5[index++] = '<hr>'




    menu5[index++] = '<a href="prtfPortfolioReport.do?method=customerStatementReport">صورتحساب مشتریان سبدگردانی</a>'



    menu5[index++] = '<a href="prtfCustomerPeriodicReport.do?method=customerPeriodicReport&new_search=true">گزارش دوره ای سبد اختصاصی</a>'






























    menu5[index++] = '<hr>'


    menu5[index++] = '<a href="portfolioTotalAssetManagement.do?method=list&new_search=true">مدیریت کل دارایی سبد</a>'




    menu5[index++] = '<hr>'



The drop-down menu is initially visible.
I expect the code to find the specific option from the drop-down list. Can you guide me on this issue?

I tried this code and it solved my problem. The code: dropdown = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "bankAccount.bankBranch.bank.bankId")))) dropdown.select_by_index(59)  I think the problem is somehow related to "NAME" attribute be non-English(# dropdown.select_by_value('پارسيان'
Persian) because the code "dropdown.select_by_value('پارسيان')" dose not work giving error: " Cannot locate option with value"
